# GLMM with presence/absence dataset

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, biostatistics, ecology

I want to know if a treatment effectively reduces the abundance of a particular species in some location. For that, I trapped the animals and identified each individual captured, releasing the animals after that. I trapped the animals 20 days with the treatment OFF and 20 days with the treatment ON. I captured 13 individuals within the experiment, but many individuals were captured only once. I had a total of 65 captures.
Then, I performed a generalized linear mixed model in R using the **lme4** package (`glmer()` function):

```
Capture ~ Treatment + (1 | Trap) + (1 | ID)
```

The factor Capture is 0 (no capture) or 1 (capture) and Treatment is ON or OFF. The Trap is the trap code, from 1 to 100. The ID is the individual identity, from 1 to 13. 
Is it correct to include the individual identity as a random effect? I am confused about what to include in the ID field for the absences. For the presences, I include the individual code, but for the absences should, I leave the random effect with no data?

Comment: Instead of a glmm, you may be better off analysing the data using some form of spatially explicit mark-recapture methodology such as https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/secr/index.html

Comment: Hmm... this is a really broad subject. Look at Hiearchical Models, look at books of Marc Kery and Andrew Royle.

Answer (score 2):

Mixed models are used to account for correlations within the levels of a grouping factor. Hence, the model

```
Capture ~ Treatment + (1 | Trap)
```

postulates that `Capture` repeated measurements from the same trap are correlated. Likewise, the model

```
Capture ~ Treatment + (1 | Trap) + (1 | ID)
```

postulates that `Capture` repeated measurements from the same trap are correlated, *and* `Capture` repeated measurements from the same ID are correlated.